# Java switch matches multiple cases

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a code snippet as follows:

```
switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
     case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
          Log.d("Location", "onResult: success");
     case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
          Log.d(TAG, "onResult: resolution needed");

 }
```

`status.getStatusCode()` return an int and all constants are int s as well.
Before switch block I log 3 values `status.getStatusCode()` is 0, `LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS` is 0 and `LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED` is 6.
But both `Log.d` statements are executed. I don't think the problem is related to my code because I executed the same logic with if-else.
What can be the problem?

Comment: You're missing `break` statements.

Comment: you need to add a `break;` statement at thend of each case block

Comment: If I don't add ``break`` statements, does the next case is executed without evaluating the condition?

Comment: Yes, it is called "fallthrough"

Answer (score 0):

You need a break statement.

Without that the case will fall though into the next case....

```
switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
     case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
          Log.d("Location", "onResult: success");
          break;
     case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
          Log.d(TAG, "onResult: resolution needed");
          break;
 }
```